# How to add icons to Carbon TextInput in svelte? (i.e. email icon on left)

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, carbon-design-system

Some of the carbon components for sveltekit like the search include icons on the left of the text input.  Button has an "icon" property, but "TextInput" does not have any properties to put an icon in the text.

Is there a simple way to add an email icon on the left of a TextInput for a login form?

https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/TextInput

https://carbon-icons-svelte.onrender.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can override some styles of both an carbon icon and the TextInput.  Add both the icon and the TextInput to your form, and you can use the style or class to override the behavior.  Set the z-index/position of the icon to overlay it onto the TextInput.  Change the padding of the TextInput to add space on the left for the icon.

[login form updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIHar.png)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Form, TextInput, Button } from "carbon-components-svelte";
    import Email from "carbon-icons-svelte/lib/Email.svelte";
    import "carbon-components-svelte/css/white.css";
    import { emailValidator } from "$lib/client/utils";

    let disabled = true;
    const textinputchange = (event: CustomEvent) => {
        disabled =  !emailValidator(event.detail);
    };
</script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="loginForm">
        <Form on:submit method="post" action="?/login" >
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p>Please enter a valid email to continue.</p>
            <div>
                <Email stroke="#eee" style="position:relative;left:10px;top:30px;z-index:999;"/>
                <TextInput style="padding:0rem 1rem 0rem 2rem;" placeholder="email" name="email" on:input={(event) => textinputchange(event)} />
            </div>
            <Button style="width:100%;margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;max-width:none;" size="field" type="submit" {disabled}>Sign In</Button>
        </Form>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .content {
        width:100%;
    }
    .loginForm {
        margin: auto;
        padding:20px;
        border:1px solid #aaa;
        width:500px;
        height:250px;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin-left:-250px;
        margin-top:-125px;
    }
</style>
```